# python get a list of length X where the sum of all values is Y

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I need to find all the combinations of lists who has their sum equal to X in the shortest possible time.

At this moment i have this:

```
def deduceArrayFromSum(arr, expectedSum, depth, maxDepth, intervalEnd, intervalStart):
    if maxDepth<=maxOffset:
        if expectedSum>0:
            i = min(intervalEnd, asum)
            while i>=intervalStart:
                if expectedSum>=i and depth<maxOffset:
                    arr[depth] = i
                    deduceArrayFromSum(arr, expectedSum-i, depth+1, maxDepth, i, intervalStart)
                i=i-1
        elif asum==0:
            foundSum(arr)
```

For every combination found, it calls `foundSum()`

I would expect that i could optimize this by making it linear instead of recursive calls, and by avoiding sending the arr variable at every call. 
Another possible way to speed this up would be by using `yield`, but I cannot seem to understand how it works.

Maybe numpy can help somehow?

---

Edit:
arr starts as [0, 0, 0]
when calling `deduceArrayFromSum(arr, 100, 0, len(arr), 100, 0)`, `foundSum()` gets called with the following params:

```
[100, 0, 0]
[99, 1, 0]
[98, 2, 0]
[98, 1, 1]
[...]
```

I hope this clears what i want from this code

Comment: Are negative numbers wanted? i.e., `[100, -1, 1]` considered part of the set?

Comment: no negative numbers. Allowe dnumbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4....

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
import itertools

def deduceArrayFromSum(arr, length, expectedSum):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(arr, length):
        if sum(combination) == expectedSum:
            foundSum(combination)
```

---

With a little refactoring, I would turn it into a generator:

```
import itertools

def combinations_with_sum(iterable, length, sum_):
    return (c in itertools.combinations(iterable, length) if sum(c) == sum_)
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
for t in combinations_with_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 5):
    print t
```

or

```
print list(combinations_with_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 5))
```

---

[This problem is NP-complete](http://xkcd.com/287/), so it will always be slow for large inputs. But you may consider researching better algorithms than brute force.

Comment: this calculates combinations, i need to fill arr with all possible values. Initially it starts as `[0] * depth`. Yes, I know that this will be slow no matter what, but i'm hoping that a pair of fresh eye could see something that I'm missing, or could come up with something new (python not being my primary language:) )

Comment: @Quamis, I'm not sure I understand. "I need to find all the combinations of lists who has their sum equal to X [with length Y]." That's what this does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as it_cr
>>> len_=3
>>> tgt=100
>>> li=[t[::-1] for t in it_cr(range(tgt+1), len_) if sum(t)==tgt]
>>> li
[(100, 0, 0), (99, 1, 0), (98, 2, 0), (97, 3, 0), (96, 4, 0), (95, 5, 0),
...
 (35, 33, 32), (34, 34, 32), (34, 33, 33)]
```

Which is easily turned into a generator:

```
def tups_sum_x(tgt, len_):
    for t in it_cr(range(tgt+1), len_):
        if sum(t)==tgt:
            yield t[::-1]
```

If you want the same order that you present, just sort:

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda t: (-t[0], t[1:]))
[(100, 0, 0), (99, 1, 0), (98, 1, 1), (98, 2, 0), (97, 2, 1), (97, 3, 0), ...
```